# What do I do if my bike won't pump with an air pump at all?

Tags: tire, innertube, pump

My bike tires will not pump up at all. I tried forever. I had this bike for a year and then it won't pump at all. I have a pump you stand on and use your 2 hands to pump. At first it was pumping air a little but now I it's not pumping. What do I do I'm confused. Do I need a new inner tube or I do I have a bad a tire?

Comment: If you pump without having the pump attached to the wheel, does air come out of the pump head?

Comment: Does the pump quickly get harder to pump, or does it stay easy to pump?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has not provided enough information to know what the problem is.

Comment: I'm voting to leave open; the answers can help someone else with a similar problem. The OP hasn't been seen since the qn was posted.

Comment: Perhaps a new tube will work? You said you've had the bike for a year....was it new to you or used?

Answer (score 12):

What kind of valve do you have?

[image]

If you have Presta valves then you need to unscrew that little knobbie thing on top until the knobbie is all the way unscrewed against the bump on the end of the shaft it rides on.

With either Presta or Schrader you can have a problem with the pump if you do not press the pump chuck **all** the way onto the valve.  Especially with Schrader there is a pin in the chuck that needs to depress a pin inside the valve to open it up.  And sometimes you need to adjust the chuck by screwing the collar on the business end of the chuck on or off a turn or two, so that the chuck will go on and seat tightly.

(When you're finished inflating a Presta valve, don't forget to turn the knobbie the other way, so that it helps hold the valve closed.  Don't wrench it tight, but just get it snug.)

Comment: last bracket is about presta rather than schrader.

Comment: @W1ll1amvl - Oops! Will fix that!

Answer (score 2):

Another possiblity is that the valve is clogged up from Slime (or other brand of puncture prevention fluid). Remove the valve core and inspect for debris clogging the valve opening.

Comment: Seems unlikely someone would have slime in their tires and not know it.

Comment: Possible if it's a "used" bike.

Answer (score 1):

Think you need to unscrew the valve on the tyre sounds as though its not allowing air into the tyre

Comment: It would be good if you explained a bit more (and maybe put a diagram). This is for example relevant to Presta valves, not Schraeder valves.